# How to start networking service

Tags: 12.04, networking

When I write below commands it says `job failed to start`. Actually I don't want to write a command every time. So how can I start my network service automatically?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
sudo service networking start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put that command in `rc.local` file.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

write that command before `exit 0`